Column height in a table
I want to make a table like this:

And i tried it with following code:
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|lc|l|lc|}
\cline{1-2} \cline{4-5}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{(1)}                        & \multirow{4}{*}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{(2)}              \\ \cline{1-2} \cline{4-5} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\((1 - p)^{160}\)} & $\Box$ &                   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\(1 - \bigg[
    \binom{160}{0} \cdot p^0 \cdot (1-p)^{160} + 
    \binom{160}{1} \cdot p^1 \cdot (1-p)^{159}
    \bigg]\)} & $\Box$ \\ \cline{1-2} \cline{4-5} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\(p^{160}\)}       & $\Box$ &                   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\(\binom{160}{2} \cdot p^2 \cdot (1-p)^{158}\)} & $\Box$ \\ \cline{1-2} \cline{4-5} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\((1 - p)^{160}\)} & $\Box$ &                   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\(\binom{160}{0} \cdot p^0 \cdot (1-p)^{160} + 
    \binom{160}{1} \cdot p^1 \cdot (1-p)^{159}\)} & $\Box$ \\ \cline{1-2} \cline{4-5} 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

and it looks like this:


Please note that we need a compileable minimum WORKING example (MWE) and the above is not compileable. In the meantime, check out the tabularx package and its \tabularxlineheight setting. This may be helpful.

Here's a solution that employs typographic struts to assure equal heights for rows 2 thru 4. It also uses an array environment instead of a tabular environment in order to eliminate the multitude of \(, \) and $ directives. It further does away with the pointless \multirow{4}{*}{} directive. Finally, it changes the column specification from {|lc|l|lc|} to {|l|c|l|l|c|} in order to do away with all \multicolumn{1}{|l|} wrappers.

\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}    % for '\binom' macro
\usepackage{amssymb}    % for '\Box' macro
% Define a typographic strut:
\newcommand\tallstrut{$\vphantom{\Big[}$} % for rows 2-4

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\[
\begin{array}{|l|c|l|l|c|}
\cline{1-2} \cline{4-5}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{(1)} & & 
\multicolumn{2}{ c|}{(2)}\\ 
\cline{1-2} \cline{4-5} 
(1 - p)^{160} & \Box\tallstrut & & 
1 - \bigl[ \binom{160}{0} \cdot p^0 \cdot (1-p)^{160} + 
           \binom{160}{1} \cdot p^1 \cdot (1-p)^{159}
    \bigr] & \Box \\ 
\cline{1-2} \cline{4-5} 
p^{160}       & \Box\tallstrut & & 
\binom{160}{2} \cdot p^2 \cdot (1-p)^{158} & \Box \\ 
\cline{1-2} \cline{4-5} 
(1 - p)^{160} & \Box\tallstrut & & 
\binom{160}{0} \cdot p^0 \cdot (1-p)^{160} + 
\binom{160}{1} \cdot p^1 \cdot (1-p)^{159} & \Box \\ 
\cline{1-2} \cline{4-5} 
\end{array}
\]
\end{table}
\end{document}


Incidentally, if you want rows 2 thru 4 to be even taller, you could change \newcommand\tallstrut{$\vphantom{\Big[}$} to \newcommand\tallstrut{$\vphantom{\bigg[}$}.

With tblr table with some columns in display math mode:
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}    % for '\binom' macro
\usepackage{amssymb}        % for '\Box' macro

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tblr}{hline{1-Z}={1-2,4-5}{solid},   vlines,
             colspec = { Q[l, m,$$] Q[c, m,$] Q[m] 
                         Q[l, m,$$] Q[c, m,$] },
             cell{1}{1,4} = {c=2}{c},
             row{2-Z} = {11mm}
            }
(1) &   &   &   (2) &       \\
(1 - p)^{160} 
    &   \square
        &   &   1 - \biggl[ \binom{160}{0} \cdot p^0 \cdot (1-p)^{160} +
                \binom{160}{1} \cdot p^1 \cdot (1-p)^{159} \biggr] 
                &   \square \\
p^{160}       
    &   \Box
        &   &   \binom{160}{2} \cdot p^2 \cdot (1-p)^{158}
                & \Box      \\
(1 - p)^{160} 
    & \Box
        &   &   \binom{160}{0} \cdot p^0 \cdot (1-p)^{160} +
                \binom{160}{1} \cdot p^1 \cdot (1-p)^{159} 
                &   \Box    \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}


Edit:
In a case, that numbers in the first row should be i circle (what I not recommend), than for example you can change table preamble and first table row to and in document preamble load package pifont:
\begin{tblr}{hline{1-Z}={1-2,4-5}{solid},   vlines,
             colspec = { Q[l, m,$$] Q[c, m,$] Q[m]
                         Q[l, m,$$] Q[c, m,$] },
             cell{1}{1,4} = {c=2}{c},
             row{1} = {mode=text, font=\Large, abovesep+=3pt},
             row{2-Z} = {11mm}
            }
\ding{192}
    &   &   &   \ding{193}
                &           \\

Result is of this changes is:

should be changes

I think you're missing 1 $ sign for 2 of your columns in the colspec. Also, I know the code of the OP didn't include this, but the image of his desired output had the numbers 1 and 2 encircled in the first row. I'd suggest loading the tikz package for this and defining a macro for circling the numbers like this:
\newcommand{\circlednumber}[1]{\tikz[baseline=(label.base)] \node[circle, draw, inner sep=1pt] (label) {#1};}

@Atex, nothing is missed.  Numbers in circles are not mentioned in question, image show squares. If OP will demand such numbers, I will show how to write them by use of a appropriate font type (for example pifont.).

perhaps OverLeaf is just bugging, then. It gives me 4 red dot signs, but when I add 1 extra $ sign to your 2nd and 5th column, it disappears. I think we're looking at different images, however, because the first image the OP showed (the one directly below his "I want to make a table like this:" statement) includes circles around those numbers. In the 2nd image (which is based on the output he was able to make by his own code), it didn't include the circles. I don't necessarily think it's because he didn't want it. Perhaps he just couldn't code it. Hence my suggestion.

@Atex, I'm not very familiar with Overleaf so can't say anything what is going wrong with compilation of mine MWE using Overleaf. Using MiKTeX or TeXLive provided code work fine, without any warning or error.

Interesting. Does that mean that whatever is loaded correctly in OverLeaf will load correctly in MiKTeX/TeXLive, but not vice versa? Also, I provided an additional answer addressing the circled numbers just in case, and I used your MWE to demonstrate the macro. I hope that's okay

@Atex, now I see, where probably should be circled numbers. Added now.

With {NiceTabular} of nicematrix, you have a key cell-space-limits (whose name is inspired by the names of the parameters of the extension cellspace) to avoid having the contents of the cells touching the horizontal rules.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
$\begin{NiceArray}{|lc|l|lc|}[cell-space-limits=2pt]
\cline{1-2} \cline{4-5}
\Block[c]{1-2}{(1)} & & & \Block[c]{1-2}{(2)} \\ 
\cline{1-2} \cline{4-5} 
(1 - p)^{160} & \Box & & 1 - \bigg[ \binom{160}{0} \cdot p^0 \cdot (1-p)^{160} + \binom{160}{1} \cdot p^1 \cdot (1-p)^{159} \bigg] & \Box \\ 
\cline{1-2} \cline{4-5} 
p^{160}       & \Box & & \binom{160}{2} \cdot p^2 \cdot (1-p)^{158} & \Box \\ 
\cline{1-2} \cline{4-5} 
(1 - p)^{160} & \Box & & \binom{160}{0} \cdot p^0 \cdot (1-p)^{160} +\binom{160}{1} \cdot p^1 \cdot (1-p)^{159} & \Box \\ 
\cline{1-2} \cline{4-5} 
\end{NiceArray}$
\end{table}

\end{document}



Since no one addressed the circled numbers in the first row which were included in the picture of your desired output, I decided to include this:

I slightly added to @Zarko's answer, so all credit goes to him for actually designing the table. I simply loaded the tikz package and created a macro for circled numbers with it. Here's the code:
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}    % for '\binom' macro
\usepackage{amssymb}        % for '\Box' macro

\usepackage{tikz} % For drawing the circles

\newcommand{\circlednumber}[1]{%
\tikz[baseline=(label.base)] \node[circle, draw, inner sep=1pt] (label) {#1};} % Macro defined to insert circles 

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tblr}{hline{1-Z}={1-2,4-5}{solid},   vlines,
             colspec = { Q[l, m,$$] Q[c, m,$$] Q[m] 
                         Q[l, m,$$] Q[c, m,$$] },
             cell{1}{1,4} = {c=2}{c},
             row{2-Z} = {11mm}
            }
\circlednumber{\scriptsize 1} &   &   &   \circlednumber{\scriptsize 2} &       \\
(1 - p)^{160} 
    &   \square
        &   &   1 - \biggl[ \binom{160}{0} \cdot p^0 \cdot (1-p)^{160} +
                \binom{160}{1} \cdot p^1 \cdot (1-p)^{159} \biggr] 
                &   \square \\
p^{160}       
    &   \Box
        &   &   \binom{160}{2} \cdot p^2 \cdot (1-p)^{158}
                & \Box      \\
(1 - p)^{160} 
    & \Box
        &   &   \binom{160}{0} \cdot p^0 \cdot (1-p)^{160} +
                \binom{160}{1} \cdot p^1 \cdot (1-p)^{159} 
                &   \Box    \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}

\end{document}

Since the macro has been defined globally, you could also use circlednumber{} for either of the other 2 answers. Just remember to load tikz. The idea of defining a global macro for this actually comes from one of egreg's answers.
Edit:
Samcarter has made me aware that a specific package for the very purpose of circling text exists. Thus, a better solution would be to use the circledsteps package and its predefined Circled macro instead. Here's the updated code:
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}    % for '\binom' macro
\usepackage{amssymb}        % for '\Box' macro

\usepackage{circledsteps} % Package for Circled macro

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tblr}{hline{1-Z}={1-2,4-5}{solid},   vlines,
             colspec = { Q[l, m,$$] Q[c, m,$$] Q[m] 
                         Q[l, m,$$] Q[c, m,$$] },
             cell{1}{1,4} = {c=2}{c},
             row{2-Z} = {11mm}
            }
\scriptstyle\Circled{1} &   &   &   \scriptstyle\Circled{2} &       \\
(1 - p)^{160} 
    &   \square
        &   &   1 - \biggl[ \binom{160}{0} \cdot p^0 \cdot (1-p)^{160} +
                \binom{160}{1} \cdot p^1 \cdot (1-p)^{159} \biggr] 
                &   \square \\
p^{160}       
    &   \Box
        &   &   \binom{160}{2} \cdot p^2 \cdot (1-p)^{158}
                & \Box      \\
(1 - p)^{160} 
    & \Box
        &   &   \binom{160}{0} \cdot p^0 \cdot (1-p)^{160} +
                \binom{160}{1} \cdot p^1 \cdot (1-p)^{159} 
                &   \Box    \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}

\end{document}

Note: In this approach, you have to define the size of your font outside the macro instead of inside of it.

See https://ctan.org/pkg/circledsteps

I wasn't aware a package existed for such a specific case! +1

Rule of thumb: a package exists for (nearly) everything

I shall keep this in mind. Lesson learned: Never underestimate any use case. There's a good chance there may be a specialized package for it;)
